# Openlayers 4 always start at top left corner

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want my map to start in the top left corner regardless of screen size. Everytime I get it set using `extent` I resize and reload, I'm not in the top left any more. I expect it to change when I resize but I need it to start with the map in the top left corner when the page loads.

```
  var extent = [0, 0, 1685, 895];
  var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    units: 'pixels',
    extent: [0, 0, 1685, 895]
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
          url: 'assets/img/map.png',
          projection: projection,
          imageExtent: [0, 0, 1685, 895]
        })
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: projection,
      center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
      zoom: 3,
      maxZoom: 8
    })
  });
```

Comment: What does that mean by top-left of the map? loading from top-left corner images?

Comment: I want the top left corner of the image (map), to start in the top left corner of the window. My assumption is I need to calculate the window center to a point in the map that places it at that location.

Comment: You should look for the isomorphy that leads from pixel to the extent. Look how many pixels are for each unit. You need a function that relates the measurements of the map with the pixels. Use `ol.extent.getTopLeft` and `ol.coordinate.add`. Remove `zoom: 3` in favor of `resolution: 1` at `ol.View`, and proportionally enlarge the extent to facilitate calculations to find that proportional center on the top left